# How to make an equivalent INSTEAD OF trigger from an AFTER trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have an AFTER trigger that I am trying to make to an equivalent INSTEAD OF trigger. I sort of understand how an INSTEAD OF trigger is executed to substitute for the firing operation, but converting it has me a little lost.

Here is my AFTER trigger:

```
go
CREATE TRIGGER tgr_priceValidation    
ON Products_Copy
FOR INSERT, DELETE AS
BEGIN
    IF exists (select UnitPrice from Products_copy where UnitPrice NOT BETWEEN 0.50 AND 500.00)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(
            ' No product is allowed to have a unit price out of the range between $0.50 and $500.00', 
            16, 
            1
        )
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
go
```

The above trigger enforces a price range rule that requires every price to be between .50 and 500 dollars.

Comment: Do you want to block the entire insert if the price doesn't fall within the range, or should valid records still be allowed to be inserted?

Comment: Hold on there. First, what sort of `DELETE` statement will cause you to have a row with a `UnitPrice` outside of your defined range? Next, do you really need to scan the *entire* table for every `INSERT`? And you ignore `UPDATE` even though it could produce an out of range value?

Comment: Make an effort. First, correct the error in your after trigger. You should refer to the virtual inserted and deleted tables, not the table on which the trigger is defined (probably - but that's a guess without good requirements). Next, TRY to write the instead-of trigger. What is different? Well, the instead-of trigger must actually perform the action on the table (insert, update, delete).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a trigger for this.  Just use a `check` constraint:

```
alter table products_copy add constraint chk_products_copy_unitprice
    check (unitPrice not between 0.50 and 500.00);
```

As a bonus, this will work for `update`s as well as `insert`s.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could just use a check constraint instead of a trigger:

```
alter table products_copy 
    add constraint chk_products_copy_unit_price_range 
    check (unitprice between 0.50 and 500.00);
```

This both simpler and more efficient than using a trigger - the only difference is that you won't get the custom error message.

Comment: I know it is impractical to do this, but I was asked to create an equivalent INSTEAD OF trigger. Check constraints not allowed.